# Flutter: Firebase Auth endless loop

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

I want to build a Flutter login screen working with Firebase Auth. I posted the Code below. When i run the App, the `_switchToHomePage()` method is called endless. So the app keeps opening an new HomeScreen until I close the app. 
Thanks for help!

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'home_page.dart';
import 'register.dart';
import 'error_dialog.dart';

class LoginForm extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _LoginFormState();
}

class _LoginFormState extends State<LoginForm> {
  final emailController = TextEditingController();
  final passwordController = TextEditingController();

  final FirebaseAuth _firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  bool _hidePassword = true;

  void _checkUserIsLoggedIn() {
    _firebaseAuth.currentUser().then((firebaseUser) {
      if (firebaseUser == null) {
        print('no user logged in');
      } else {
        print('User logged in');
        _switchToHomePage();
      }
    });
  }

  void _switchToHomePage() {
    print('switching to home page...');
    Navigator.push(
        context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomePage()));
    this.deactivate();
  }

  void _login() {
    String email = emailController.text;
    String password = passwordController.text;
    _firebaseAuth
        .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password)
        .then((firebaseUser) {
      if (firebaseUser != null) {
        print('Login succesfull');
        _switchToHomePage();
      } else {
        throw Exception('FirebaseUser is null');
      }
    }).catchError((exception) {
      //TODO make better error messages
      print(exception.message);
      ErrorDialog(
          context: this.context,
          title: 'Error',
          message: exception.message);
    });
  }

  void _showRegisterScreen() {
    Navigator.push(
        context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => RegisterForm()));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    _checkUserIsLoggedIn();
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Login')),
        body: ListView(
          padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(15, 30, 15, 0),
          children: <Widget>[
            Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 60)),
            Text(
              'placeholder',
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.teal,
                fontSize: 40,
              ),
            ),
            Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 60)),
            Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 40)),
            TextField(
              controller: emailController,
              keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                  prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.email),
                  labelText: 'E-Mailadresse',
                  border: UnderlineInputBorder()),
            ),
            Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20)),
            TextField(
              controller: passwordController,
              obscureText: _hidePassword,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                  labelText: 'Passwort',
                  border: UnderlineInputBorder(),
                  prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.security),
                  suffixIcon: IconButton(
                    icon: Icon(Icons.remove_red_eye),
                    color: _hidePassword
                        ? Theme.of(context).primaryColor
                        : Colors.grey,
                    onPressed: () => this.setState(() {
                      _hidePassword = !_hidePassword;
                    }),
                  )),
            ),
            Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 5)),
            Container(
              child: FlatButton(
                onPressed: () => print('Forgot password'),
                child: Text(
                  'Passwort vergessen?',
                  style: TextStyle(color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor),
                ),
              ),
              width: double.infinity,
              alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
            ),
            Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 40)),
            RaisedButton(
              onPressed: _login,
              color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
              child: Text(
                'Login',
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
              ),
            ),
            Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20)),
            FlatButton(
              onPressed: _showRegisterScreen,
              child: Text(
                'Neuen Account erstellen',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 16,
                  color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
                ),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you get that, is because `_checkUserIsLoggedIn();` which contains navigation to the `HomePage` is the first method inside `build` method. Inside the `build()` method you have `setState()` on the `TextField`, therefore everytime the state is changing then the `build()` method is getting called and `_checkUserIsLoggedIn()` is also getting called. To solve that try the following:

```
@override
initState() {
  super.initState();
   _firebaseAuth.currentUser().then((firebaseUser) {
      if (firebaseUser == null) {
        print('no user logged in');
      } else {
        print('User logged in');
        _switchToHomePage();
      }
    });
}
```

Inside the lifecycle method `initState()` check if the user is logged in and navigate to the `HomePage`. Also remove the method `_checkUserIsLoggedIn();` from the `build` method

Answer (score 0):

I just solved it. I replaced:

```
Navigator.push(
        context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => RegisterForm()));
```

with

```
Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
        context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomePage()), (e) => false);
```